# Running project on Android Studio fails because of missing app module

Tags: android, android-studio

When I press on run in Android studio an Edit configuration windows pops up and says "Error: Module not specified".

I have added sources to the application libs folder by manually making a folder structure android/hardware/automotive/vehicle/V2_0 and copied the files in there.

Build completes without errors.
I haven't edited the MainActivity -class so it is all pre-generated code.

I believe this error has something to do with incorrect syntax when including but it seems to be hard to get it working :)

this is my settings.gradle file:

`include ':app'
project(':app').projectDir = new File('libs/android/hardware/automotive/vehicle/V2_0')`

and this is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

`android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.s26150.testingopencar"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    compile project(":android.hardware.automotive.vehicle.V2_0")

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}`

What could be the issue here?
thanks in advance.

Comment: This might be the cause of issue `compile project(":android.hardware.automotive.vehicle.V2_0")`. What are you trying to do with this?

Comment: under libs folder i have a folder structure android.hardware.automotive.vehicle.V2_0 
there I have put Java files to be used as a library @NovoLucas